# TouchableOpacity change color of text on click

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

im new at coding, new at React too, im trying to change my text color(and click again to change back to the original) with a click.

```
  function lastTouches() {
    
      return (
        <Box>
          <Box>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text>
                Change Color
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Box>
      );
    }
    
    export default lastTouches;
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? [React Native / Docs / TouchableOpacity](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First import usestate from react;

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

    function lastTouches() {


const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const Press1 = () => setActive(!active);

  const buttonTextStyle = {
    color: active ? 'green' : 'red'
  };

              return (
                <Box>
                  <Box>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={Press1}>
                      <Text style={buttonTextStyle}>
                        Change Color
                      </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </Box>
              );
            }
            
            export default lastTouches;
```

It will work! For React Js, use button and call function;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the text of the button, you will have to define styles for the `<Text>` component.

```
<Text style={{ color: /* state value here */ }}>Press Here</Text>
```

## Example

The code below is a fork of the Function Component example found on the documentation.

See: [React Native / Docs / TouchableOpacity](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingHorizontal: 10
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#DDDDDD",
    padding: 10,
    border: "thin solid grey"
  }
});

const App = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const onPress = () => setActive(!active);

  const buttonTextStyle = {
    color: active ? 'green' : 'red'
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={onPress}
      >
        <Text style={buttonTextStyle}>Press Here</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

If you want each button to behave independently, you will need to create a new component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    gap: 10
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#DDDDDD",
    padding: 10,
    border: "thin solid grey"
  }
});

const StatefulButton = (props) => {
  const { color, activeColor } = props;
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const onPress = () => setActive(!active);
  const buttonTextStyle = {
      color: active ? activeColor : color,
      fontStyle: active ? 'unset' : 'italic',
      fontWeight: active ? 'bold' : 'normal'
    };
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onPress}>
      <Text style={buttonTextStyle}>Press Here</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatefulButton color="red" activeColor="green" />
      <StatefulButton color="magenta" activeColor="cyan" />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Its working!!! Another question, if i make another div with the same code both div's change in the click, there's a short way (maybe in React Native) to change the color of a div without making various functions?

Comment: @Guilherme I added an alternative example below.